# What is the easiest way to display products added last month in Wordpress Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I want to create a Woocommerce shop page that **only displays products published last month**. What is the best way to accomplish this? I've tried several plugins without succes. From my understanding you can accomplish this with standard Woocommerce, Woocommerce blocks and some shortcode.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: did you try this [Woocommerce: only show products between start and end dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302186/woocommerce-only-show-products-between-start-and-end-dates)

Comment: Thank you for your time and quick respond.

I'm quite new to wordpress, I'm not sure how to apply the code (where do I edit it ect.). Do I do it in Wordpress Admin panel or with a SSH connection editing a file?

Comment: You have to put this code in your active theme functions.php file.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out and let you know if I managed to get it to work.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Comment: Please note that you can always comment on your own posts and on answers to your own questions. Having <50 reputation does not change that.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a shortcode for you. Which will return all products from last month. you can use this shortcode anywhere: `[wc_get_products_last_month]`

```
add_shortcode('wc_get_products_last_month', function( $atts, $content = null ){

    $start_date = array(
        'year'  => date("Y", strtotime("first day of previous month")),
        'month' => date("n", strtotime("first day of previous month")),
        'day'   => date("j", strtotime("first day of previous month"))
    );

    $end_date = array(
        'year'  => date("Y", strtotime("last day of previous month")),
        'month' => date("n", strtotime("last day of previous month")),
        'day'   => date("j", strtotime("last day of previous month"))
    );


    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'after'     => $start_date,
                'before'    => $end_date,
                'inclusive' => true,
            ),
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        while( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
            // Get $product object from product ID
            $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );

            // Do you stuff here
            //_e( $product->get_name() );

        }

    } else {
        echo 'No Posts';
    }

    wp_reset_query();
});
```

Tested and Worked.

Comment: I'm sorry that I have to ask, but how do I apply this code? I can add it to the function.php file from the theme as mentioned above and then I can create a block using the shortcode or do I put the shortcode on the page? I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use it.

Comment: You can do both. you can use shortcode as [wc_get_products_last_month] in block or pages

Comment: function.php:
https://gyazo.com/26ac0b617d01078e784749df2f5226dc
Elementor shortcode:
https://gyazo.com/ec3d3bbf45a21c6805710ddb348d0547, both shortcode plugin and shortcode block won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Combination of these two answers (credit goes to them. I am just updating code by your requirements). put this code in your active theme functions.php file.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66528155/6469645

[Woocommerce : only show products between start and end dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302186/woocommerce-only-show-products-between-start-and-end-dates)

```
function custom_meta_query( $meta_query ){

    $start_date = array(
        'year'  => date("Y", strtotime("first day of previous month")),
        'month' => date("n", strtotime("first day of previous month")),
        'day'   => date("j", strtotime("first day of previous month"))
    );

    $end_date = array(
        'year'  => date("Y", strtotime("last day of previous month")),
        'month' => date("n", strtotime("last day of previous month")),
        'day'   => date("j", strtotime("last day of previous month"))
    );

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'after'     => $start_date,
                'before'    => $end_date,
                'inclusive' => true,
            ),
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    return $args;
}

// The main shop and archives meta query
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'custom_product_query_meta_query', 10, 2 );
function custom_product_query_meta_query( $meta_query, $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() )
        return custom_meta_query( $meta_query );
}

// The shortcode products query
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'custom__shortcode_products_query', 10, 3 );
function custom__shortcode_products_query( $query_args, $atts, $loop_name ) {
    if( ! is_admin() )
        $query_args['meta_query'] = custom_meta_query( $query_args['meta_query'] );
    return $query_args;
}

// The widget products query
add_filter( 'woocommerce_products_widget_query_args', 'custom_products_widget_query_arg', 10, 1 );
function custom_products_widget_query_arg( $query_args ) {
    if( ! is_admin() )
        $query_args['meta_query'] = custom_meta_query( $query_args['meta_query'] );
    return $query_args;
}
```

Comment: It's doing something, but not sure what. I have 10 products in the shop and adjust the publish dates, the products that I give a date of today won't display, but product from 1 month ago, 2 months ago and even 3 years ago are still showing.

Answer (score 0):

Solution here: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/show-latest-30-days-products-in-woocommerce/258276

```
function baba_recent_products() {
    //return 'This is where the recent products should show up if I get the shortcode working. ';
    
    
    global $woocommerce_loop;

        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'per_page'  => '48',
            'columns'   => '2',
            'orderby'   => 'date',
            'order'     => 'desc'
        ), $atts ) );

        $meta_query = WC()->query->get_meta_query();

        $args = array(
            'post_type'             => 'product',               
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
            'posts_per_page'        => $per_page,
            'orderby'               => $orderby,
            'order'                 => $order,
            'meta_query'            => $meta_query
        );

        ob_start();

        $products = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', $args, $atts ) );

        $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $columns;

        if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <?php endif;

        wp_reset_postdata();

        return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $columns . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
    }
    
    
    add_shortcode( 'baba_recent_products', 'baba_recent_products' );

function filter_where($where = '') {
    //posts in the last 30 days
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
```